# Yii AR join not working when using findAll

Tags: php, yii

I have two tables `menus` and `lang_menus`. My `Menus` model is as follows :

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
                'menulanguages'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'MenuLangs', 'menuId'),
    );
}
...
public function getMenus(){
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "t.clientId = ".Yii::app()->user->clientId." AND menulanguages.languageId = ".Yii::app()->user->userlanguage;


        $count = Menus::model()->with('menulanguages')->count($criteria);

        $pages=new CPagination($count);
        //Results per page
        $pages->pageSize=10;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        $menus = Menus::model()->with('menulanguages')->findAll($criteria);
        return array('menus' => $menus, 'paging' => $pages);
    }
```

This is throwing the error `Unknown column 'menulanguages.languageId'`.
The error is in the line `$menus = Menus::model()->with('menulanguages')->findAll($criteria);`.

Surprisingly I am getting the value of the variable `$count` correctly.

On looking at the log I can see that the SQL query that is running for the findAll query is :

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`, `t`.`clientId` AS `t0_c1`, `t`.`restaurantId` AS `t0_c2` FROM `posif_menus` `t` WHERE (t.clientId = 1 AND menulanguages.languageId = 2) LIMIT 10
```

which means the join has not taken place. Whereas proper join query is running for the count value. Am I doing something wrong ?
Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`together()` of CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#together-detail) or [`together` property of CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#together-detail):

```
$menus = Menus::model()->with('menulanguages')->together()->findAll($criteria);
```

or:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "t.clientId = ".Yii::app()->user->clientId." AND menulanguages.languageId = ".Yii::app()->user->userlanguage;
$criteria->together=true;
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you @bool.dev , but how do I get to display the data I got from the second table ? I tried `echo $menu->name` and `echo $menu->menulanguages->name` but it is not working. But I am able to see the value of `name` (which is a field in the second table) on doing a var_dump on the result object.

Comment: $menu is an array of menu objects each with related menulanguages objects, so you'll have to do `echo $result['menus'][0]->menulanguages[0]->name;`

Comment: PERFECT .. You are awesome ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. apply joining table in cdbcriteria..

```
public function getMenus(){
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "t.clientId = ".Yii::app()->user->clientId." AND                                               menulanguages.languageId = ".Yii::app()->user->userlanguage;
        $criteria->with = array('menulanguages');

        $count = Menus::model()->count($criteria);

        $pages=new CPagination($count);
        //Results per page
        $pages->pageSize=10;
        $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

        $menus = Menus::model()->findAll($criteria);
        return array('menus' => $menus, 'paging' => $pages);
    }
```

Comment: It is not working. Showing the same SQL error. The query is still the same. Also it should be `$criteria->with = 'menulanguages'`

Comment: try this.. $criteria->with = array('menulanguages');

Comment: I got it working with bool.dev 's solution. But still cant figure out how to print the value of the joined table's fields in the view. I tried `echo $menu->name` and `echo $menu->menulanguages->name` but it is not working. But I am able to see the value of name (which is a field in the second table) on doing a var_dump on the result object.