# Yii CGridView sorting and searching with relation table

Tags: yii

I have 3 tables in my database,

Image is below, I have followed http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

to get final grid with with search and sort purpose. so i have connected 2 tables in `search()` function like

> ```
>   public function search()
>   {
>       // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
>       // should not be searched.
>
>       $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
>
>                 $criteria->with = array( 'bposite' );
>                 $criteria->together = false;
>                 $criteria->with = array( 'client' );
>       $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
> //        $criteria->compare('client_id',$this->client_id);
> //        $criteria->compare('bposite_id',$this->bposite_id);
>       $criteria->compare('userid',$this->userid,true);
>       $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
>                 $criteria->compare( 'bposite.name', $this->bposite_search, true );                
>                 $criteria->compare( 'client.name', $this->client_search, true );
>
>
>       return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
>           'criteria'=>$criteria,
>                             'sort'=>array(
>                                 'attributes'=>array(
>                                     'client_search'=>array(
>                                         'asc'=>'client.name',
>                                         'desc'=>'client.name DESC',
>                                     ),
>                                     'bposite_search'=>array(
>                                         'asc'=>'bposite.name',
>                                         'desc'=>'bposite.name DESC',
>                                     ),
>                                     '*',
>                                 ),
>                             ),
>       ));
>   }
> }
> ```

But I am getting result for client, bposite seach and sort is showing problem like

```
>     Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1>
>     <p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bposite.name'
> in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT
> COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) FROM `clientbposites` `t`  LEFT OUTER JOIN
> `client` `client` ON (`t`.`client_id`=`client`.`id`)  WHERE
> (bposite.name LIKE :ycp0)
> (D:\wamp\www\yi\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:516)</p><pre>#0
> D:\wamp\www\yi\framework\db\CDbCommand.php(411):
> CDbCommand->queryInternal('fetchColumn', 0, Array)

how can implement non-related table with cgridview search and sort options.
```

[image: My database table and result girdview]

Comment: is there error when you change `$criteria->together` to `true`?

Comment: No error, just tried. i got an answer from below..

Answer (score 10):

I've made a step by step blog post about this. Feel free to read it and ask questions if you're stuck. Instead of repeating myself by writing everything here too, here's the link: http://www.mrsoundless.com/post/2011/05/09/Searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-CGridView.aspx

It seems to have helped a bunch of people. Hope it helps you too :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much, i got an answer from your blog.

**$criteria->with = array('client', 'bposite');**

I got it from comments area. we need to add all relations in single array. Thank you so much for your great help. :)

Comment: I also had to use `$critaria->together` to make this work. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10697799/2329962) for more info.

Comment: @MrSoundless your page is no longer available. Can you please share/update your blog link?